# Error: ORA-17008 - Closed Connection

Tags: oracle, plsql

I try to run some PL/SQL on SQL Developer. It gives me an error although that same code works in SQL Plus. This error is always the same, whatever PL/SQL code I try with.

What could be wrong?

[image]

```
<<outer>>
DECLARE
    xy varchar2(20);
begin
    <<inner>>
    declare
        ww varchar2(20):='welcome';
    begin
        select ename into xy from emp where empno=7369;
        dbms_output.put_line(ww);
        dbms_output.put_line(xy);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: You may have a corrupt setting in SQL Developer. I would suggest to delete the database connection from SQL Developer and create it again.

Comment: i tried the same code without inner and outer codes and it is worked... any tips about that?

Answer (score 4):

> i tried the same code without inner and outer codes and it is worked

`inner` and `outer` are key words, part of the ANSI 92 SQL syntax. So, although those aren't reserved words, it be safer to use something which is not a keyword e.g. `<< inner_loop >>` .

I think the main thing is specifying a label outside the `DECLARE`. Labels are ways of sub-dividing a program body, so that doesn't really make sense. Putting the label outside the program throws ORA-06550 in PL/SQL Developer, which is slightly more controlled than the error you get, but I think this is the cause.